# How to get CRFSuite to work on Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, crf

I am trying to get [CRFSuite](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/) to work on Mac OS X.  The author only has binaries for Windows and Linux, but does provide the source package.  I am guessing I need to somehow compile the source into a Mac OS X executable?  This I have no idea how to do.  I did some research on this, but nothing actually works.  I also asked a PhD student at the university specifically this problem--he told me it would be very difficult.

I have been able to get CRFSuite to work by using WineSkin, but that's a workaround and not a real solution.

Ideally when I open the Terminal I should be able to invoke CRFSuite by just typing "crfsuite" and not jumping through hoops to pipe commands to a WineSkin Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy with `homebrew`.

First go to `homebrew` website - [here](http://brew.sh) and install it. It is very simple.

Then do the following in Terminal:

```
brew tap brewsci/science
brew install crfsuite
```

If anything goes wrong, use

```
brew doctor
```

Once you are up and running, I find it a good idea to occasionally do the following to upgrade `brew` itself and the installed packages:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

There are lots of gret, up-to-date packages that are so easy to install using `homebrew`, I use the following:

```
ant
basex
cmake
coreutils
exiftool
exiv2
faac
ffmpeg
fontconfig
freetype
gawk
gd
gettext
ghostscript
gnu-sed
gnuplot
ilmbase
imagemagick
jasper
jbig2dec
jhead
jp2a
jpeg
lame
leptonica
libpng
libtiff
libtool
lighttpd
little-cms2
lua
lynx
mad
netpbm
opencv
openexr
openssl
p7zip
parallel
pcre
perlmagick
pipebench
pipemeter
pkg-config
platypus
proftpd
pv
qt
readline
redis
sleuthkit
sox
sqlite
sqlitebrowser
tag
tesseract
tree
wget
x264
xvid
xz
```

If you want to look for additional packages, just use:

```
brew search <search string>
```